# Is it possible to reuse glsl vertex shader output later?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I have a huge mesh(100k triangles) that needs to be drawn a few times and blend together every frame. Is it possible to reuse the vertex shader output of the first pass of mesh, and skip the vertex stage on later passes? I am hoping to save some cost on the vertex pipeline and rasterization.

Targeted OpenGL 3.0, can use features like transform feedback.

Comment: 100k is not a buge number i would say. Mention the hardware/gpu you plan your app for.

Comment: Targeted on mordern consumer pc. I have test cards including nvidia GTS450, GT570, GT650M, and some equivalent ati cards.

Comment: this is for a terrain system, 100k is one patch. I am trying to control the total triangles drawn per frame to around 1 million. Currently the terrain system consumes around 700k. Most of them are close up patches(highest LOD)

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, it's in the core specification. I meant "feature"

Comment: *"can use features like transform feedback."* - Well, then you already seem to know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer your basic question first, then answer your real question.

Yes, you can store the output of vertex transformation for later use. This is called Transform Feedback. It requires OpenGL 3.x-class hardware or better (aka: DX10-hardware).

The way it works is in two stages. First, you have to set your program up to have feedback-based varyings. You do this with [`glTransformFeedbackVaryings`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTransformFeedbackVaryings). This must be done *before* linking the program, in a similar way to things like [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation).

Once that's done, you need to bind buffers (given how you set up your transform feedback varyings) to `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` with `glBindBufferRange`, thus setting up which buffers the data are written into. Then you start your feedback operation with glBeginTransformFeedback and proceed as normal. You can use a [primitive query object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Query_Object#Primitive_queries) to get the number of primitives written (so that you can draw it later with `glDrawArrays`), or if you have 4.x-class hardware (or AMD 3.x hardware, all of which supports ARB_transform_feedback2), you can [render without querying the number of primitives](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Transform_feedback_rendering). That would save time.

Now for your *actual question*: it's probably not going to help buy you any real performance.

You're drawing terrain. And terrain doesn't really get any transformation. Typically you have a matrix multiplication or two, possibly with normals (though if you're rendering for shadow maps, you don't even have that). That's it.

Odds are very good that if you shove 100,000 vertices down the GPU with such a simple shader, you've probably saturated the GPU's ability to render them all. You'll likely bottleneck on primitive assembly/setup, and that's not getting any faster.

So you're probably not going to get much out of this. Feedback is generally used for either *generating* triangle data for later use (effectively pseudo-compute shaders), or for preserving the results from *complex* transformations like matrix palette skinning with dual-quaternions and so forth. A simple matrix multiply-and-go will barely be a blip on the radar.

You can try it if you like. But odds are you won't have any problems. Generally, the best solution is to employ some form of deferred rendering, so that you only have to render an object once + X for every shadow it casts (where X is determined by the shadow mapping algorithm). And since shadow maps require different transforms, you wouldn't gain anything from feedback anyway.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I have implemented transform feedback in my engine. Doesn't `glDrawArrays` still push all data through the vertex pipeline? Perhaps I should word my question as "reuse rasterization result"~

Comment: @shenbo: Yes. It's called "deferred rendering."

Comment: I am already using deferred method for lighting calculation. Just wondering if there's any way of skipping vertex shader stage completely. Seems not possible so far. Answer accepted.

Comment: @shenbo: Like Nicol Bolas already explained, you're probably hitting the primitive setup through limit. Primitive setup happens way vertex transformation, on the already transformed geometry. So any caching you'd do on the vertex shader output will just feed as much data into primitive setup as before and saturate it just as much. A image based caching solution is the already suggested deferred rendering method: For every framebuffer sample the transformed geometry is stored, so that it can be used for later computations initiated by drawing a single viewport sized quad.

Comment: @datenwolf: True. I could draw the mesh once, and generate a screen sized quad as a pixel mask for further shading. I'll try this later :)